# Typo3: One Editor / Different content types on different pages

Tags: permissions, typo3, typoscript

I'm working on a TYPO3 page. configure an editor.
When configuring an editor a few problems have surfaced!
The editor should be able to insert different content elements on certain pages.
The Editor should add these content types on the following pages.

> Home    ->   "Regular text element"
>   News    ->   "Text & Images"

Can anyone tell me how to setup the user and group premissions?
Regards Tim

Comment: You should add your solution as an answer and accept it then ;-)

Comment: Done! Thx, look at the answer :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it:

Content Type: "Regular text element"

```
[usergroup = 1]
TCEFORM.tt_content.CType {
    removeItems = header, textpic, image, bullets, table, uploads, multimedia, 
    mailform, search, login, menu, shortcut, html, script, splash, div, list
}
[GLOBAL]
```

Content Type: "Text & Images"

```
[usergroup = 1]
TCEFORM.tt_content.CType {
    removeItems = header, text, image, bullets, table, uploads, multimedia, 
    mailform, search, login, menu, shortcut, html, script, splash, div, list
}
[GLOBAL]
```